# How to change indexes keys an array of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have an array of object , `[{name:'abc'},{name:'def'},{name:'ghi'}]`. When I loop `map()` on this array I am getting array like `[0:{name:'abc'},1:{name:'def'},2:{name:'ghi'}]`. I want to change index number to string values like `['string1':{name:'abc'},'string2':{name:'def'},'string3:{name:'ghi'}]`. Actually it will change ( 0, 1,2 ) indexes to string . I tried but didn't find any solution . Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue . ?

any simple example will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `['string1':{name:'abc'},'string2':{name:'def'},'string3:{name:'ghi'}]` is not valid

Comment: @Andreas . Yes , I know but I have requirment

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: @toesslab What do you mean ?

Comment: *"I tried but didn't find any solution"* Show us what you've tried

Comment: _"I know but I have requirment"_ - It's irrelevant what the requirement says when it isn't possible because of invalid syntax o.O

Comment: and yes, you can't have associative arrays in JS, `[string1:{name:'abc'}]` is invalid, however, `{string1:{name:'abc'}}` is valid (object)

Comment: As @Cid mentioned. Show us what is it that you tried that didn't work out

Comment: You need to use an object literal instead of an array.

Comment: When you say you have a requirement it means it is most likely a homework question

Comment: @expressjs123 Could you please try a simple example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a data structure that allows indexing by a given key, you should try an `object` or a `Map`. Use an `object` if you're just trying to do something simple.

With that, you should have:

```js
const names = {
  string1: {name:'abc'},
  string2: {name:'def'},
  string3: {name:'ghi'}
}
```

But I guess it can be simplified to this:

```js
const names = {
  string1: 'abc',
  string2: 'def',
  string3: 'ghi'
}
```

But if you want to go the long way, which can give you something similar.

```js
const names = [{name:'abc'},{name:'def'},{name:'ghi'}];
const entries = Object.fromEntries(names.entries());
const mappedNames = Object.keys(entries).map(key => [`string${key}`, entries[key]])

const newNames = Object.fromEntries(mappedNames)
```

which would give you:

```js
{
  string0: {name:'abc'},
  string1: {name:'def'},
  string2: {name:'ghi'}
}
```

But you can't change the value of an array index.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you described `['string1':{name:'abc'},'string2':{name:'def'},'string3:{name:'ghi'}]` is invalid. Instead, combine `for-of` loops and `object literals`.

```js
let obj = {};
let ind = 0;
for (const object of /*array name*/) {
  obj["string" + ind] = object;
  ind += 1;
```